# What are some ways to get your party to stop doing stupid things?

Tags: problem-players

What are ways to stop them from trying to pee on a chest or throw their pet at the enemy or eat a wall?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. To address concerns about social issues, the site needs information about the folks involved. You might not be able to stop a party of 4-year-olds to whom you've just introduced to role-playing from doing the dumb, but if your players are 50-year-old professionals, more options present themselves. Please include more information about the group, then the site can start offering deterrents. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Specifically, our site works best when you describe to us a specific, real problem you are actually facing, and then request a solution to that problem. Not "tell me some ways to handle these vague examples", but instead tell us: "I am experiencing (describe what's happening) and it's causing (describe them) problems for the group. The people involved are (describe your group briefly), some/all of them are causing this problem. We have tried (describe what you've attempted to do to resolve the problem, if anything). How can I resolve this situation?" Knowing ages would also help.

Comment: I’d would let them... with realistic, serious results.

Answer (score 4):

If you're having a serious problem with one player ruining play for the entire group, perhaps you should sit down and have a talk with them about it before a session. If they refuse to listen, it's always possible to replace a single player, but if this is a recurring theme with *all* of your players, then perhaps you should consider running a comedy-style campaign instead of preventing everyone from enjoying the game in the way they want to.